# How to get sum of concatenated rows in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

my datatable is this:[image]

and the table i need is :
[image]

i used a function to concatenate rows in ms access as follows:

```
    Public Function GetList(SQL As String _
                            , Optional ColumnDelimeter As String = ", " _
                            , Optional RowDelimeter As String = vbCrLf) As String
'PURPOSE: to return a combined string from the passed query
'ARGS:
'   1. SQL is a valid Select statement
'   2. ColumnDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each column
'   3. RowDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each row
'RETURN VAL: Concatenated list
'DESIGN NOTES:
'EXAMPLE CALL: =GetList("Select Col1,Col2 From Table1 Where Table1.Key = " & OuterTable.Key)

Const PROCNAME = "GetList"
Const adClipString = 2
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sResult As String

On Error GoTo ProcErr

Set oConn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set oRS = oConn.Execute(SQL)

sResult = oRS.GetString(adClipString, -1, ColumnDelimeter, RowDelimeter)

If Right(sResult, Len(RowDelimeter)) = RowDelimeter Then
    sResult = Mid$(sResult, 1, Len(sResult) - Len(RowDelimeter))
End If

GetList = sResult
oRS.Close
oConn.Close

CleanUp:
    Set oRS = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing

Exit Function
ProcErr:
    ' insert error handler
    Resume CleanUp

End Function
```

and the query i used is:

```
SELECT OB.Operation_Type, OB.Machine_Type, OB.Attatchment, GetList("Select Operation_Name From OB As T1 Where T1.Operation_Type = """ & [ob].[Operation_Type] & """ and  T1.Machine_Type = """ & [ob].[Machine_Type] & """ and  T1.Attatchment = """ & [ob].[Attatchment] & """ ",""," + ") AS Expr1 
FROM ob
GROUP BY ob.Operation_Type, Machine_Type, Attatchment;
```

that is giving me result

[image]

i need sum of SAM of concatenated rows.
please help
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SAM is a number field, you can simply add a `SUM()` aggregate. Unless I'm missing something.

```
SELECT OB.Operation_Type, OB.Machine_Type, OB.Attatchment, 
  GetList("Select Operation_Name From OB As T1 Where T1.Operation_Type = """ & [ob].[Operation_Type] & """ and  T1.Machine_Type = """ & [ob].[Machine_Type] & """ and  T1.Attatchment = """ & [ob].[Attatchment] & """ ",""," + ") AS Expr1,
  SUM([SAM]) AS SumSAM
FROM ob
GROUP BY ob.Operation_Type, Machine_Type, Attatchment;
```